# electron app slowdown after updating packages

Tags: electron

i am currently working on a wexond browser fork, i have its native electron version updated and i re wrote some of its code to support communicating with its ipc directly instead of relying on the electron remote for most of its processing and communication to the electron process now the only issue is im trying to rewrite a for of the wexond/rpc to add into the wexond browser base updated project for better compatibility with its electron version i updated all the packages in the rpc and the wexond application and when i build and run the application after all the updates it loads the browser view very slowley and it loads the app fast but the actual browser project is slow when loading webpages and in the consule theres a whole host of ipc communications failing, i tried re writing the ipc code for wexonds ipc communications but that dident work, i really need help with this one its confusing me.